# Why does a do-while loop run faster than a function call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I was trying to emulate the concept of a block from Ruby in javascript. I thought of an idea to use a do while loop that only executes once by having a false condition in the while segment. That way regardless of any variables, the code in the brackets will always execute but only execute once. Additionally, I wanted to compare that in terms of time to a regular function call that has the same behavior. This is the code i used:

```js
//code block time tests
var i = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime()/1000;
while(i < 100000){
  (function(){i++;})()
}
console.log((new Date().getTime()/1000)-start);

//function call test 0.016000032424926758
var j = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime()/1000;
while(j < 100000){
  do {j++;}while(false);
}
console.log((new Date().getTime()/1000)-start);


//do once test 0.002000093460083008
```

However, it seems that the function call is much slower than the do while loop. Why is this? Shouldn't functional calls be more optimized than do while loops?

Comment: Why do you need to emulate Ruby blocks? Aren't [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) the same concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that *calling* a function is slow; it's that *creating* a function is slow. Your existing code creates a new, anonymous function and executes it *every time you go through the loop*. That's much slower than defining a function once and then calling it many times because function creation is relatively slow.

```
// TEST 1
// Your existing first test creates an anonymous function on every run
//code block time tests
var i = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime()/1000;
while(i < 100000){
  (function(){i++;})()
}
console.log((new Date().getTime()/1000)-start);
// something like 0.009999990463256836 seconds

// TEST 2
// Your second test, with no function at all
var j = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime()/1000;
while(j < 100000){
  do {j++;}while(false);
}
console.log((new Date().getTime()/1000)-start);
// something like 0.0010001659393310547 seconds

// TEST 3
// Here's what happens with a named function, defined only once
function aRealFunction(n) {
    return n+1;
}
var i = 0;
var start = new Date().getTime()/1000;
while(i < 100000){
  i = aRealFunction(i);
}
console.log((new Date().getTime()/1000)-start);
// something like 0.0009999275207519531 seconds - ten times faster
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, I was trying to emulate the concept of a block from Ruby in javascript. I thought of an idea to use a do while loop that only executes once by having a false condition in the while segment.

Just FYI, that serves no purpose whatsoever. :-) There is no difference between

```
do {
    /* something */
}
while (false);
```

and

```
{
    /* something */
}
```

except that the former involves more code and a pointless test. In JavaScript (and most other languages using similar syntax, like Java, C#, C++, and C), a block doesn't need to be associated with anything, it can be freestanding.

> However, it seems that the function call is much slower than the do while loop. Why is this?

Lots of reasons:

1. You're not only *calling* the function in your loop, you're *creating* it in your loop.
2. Every call to a function involves overhead: Creating a new execution context and associated binding object for locals, populating that, setting the value of `this`, etc.
3. Referencing `i` from within the function requires that the JavaScript engine first look on the binding object for the function call's execution context and then, if it doesn't find `i`, follow the link from that context to the enclosing context so it can check *its* binding object for `i`. (E.g., following the closure chain.)

While the JavaScript engine (V8, in this case) can optimize those things, by default V8's built-in compiler is a two-stage optimizing compiler: It does an initial fast compilation which is correct but not necessarily optimized, and then goes back and optimizes things if they seem like hot spots. The threshold for whether something is a hot spot is complicated, but Crankshaft (the optimizing compiler) probably doesn't kick in until about the 10,000th iteration, so you aren't seeing all of the benefits of that optimization.

---

Side note: As of ES2015, if a block contains any block-scoped declarations (`let`, `const`, `class`, etc.), the block gets its own binding object for those declarations. (ES5 and earlier didn't have block scope.)

Comment: Woah i didnt know you could have an anonymous block in javascript! thanks!

Comment: @JoshWeinstein: Expect them to become more common now that ES2015+ code is becoming more widespread. We don't need scoping functions anymore to avoid creating globals, we can just use scoping *blocks*. :-)